# How often Geth/Parity access the archive chain files? Can I store remote?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, wallets, parity

I'm running a full archive node to receive and send funds (ETH & other tokens also). The size of the blockchain is very large, so I'm thinking about storing it remotely and mount as an sshfs network drive. (mounting a Sia storage with repertory hmmm, will be very sexy)
Is it fast enough, or that's a very bad idea? Parity? Geth? What's about other coins (for example Bitcoin)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only when that data is being queried, e.g. through JSONRPC.

You don't need an archive node just for sending ETH and tokens, though. They are only useful if you want to get the state for any block at any time. A full node is sufficient for most tasks, and is only about 200GB in size right now, compared to 3TB for an archive node.

Comment: Thank you!
So when I check a balance of an address/account with JSON-RPC, it will touch the blocks or just the state? (also a question, where the state is stored, is it a folder on my computer?)

Comment: Yes, when you query for (for example) balance of an address, at a specific block, it will read that block from the file system. The state is stored in `~/.ethereum`, for Geth and `~/.local/share/io.parity.ethereum/` for Parity. If you just want to query the current state, a full node is sufficient.

Comment: Ohh so a full node only saves the state (~200 GB), and queries that? (I don't need old balance data, just current)
If that is true, I can't store the 200GB on a remote storage, because querying will be slow. ?